# Why are my radio buttons not toggling state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to partially follow the react tutorial.

I'm at this point trying to create a component that has 2 input fields of type "radio". One is checked by default. I'm trying to mimic a behavior whereby if I click on the other radio button, the currently checked one will  be turned off, and the one clicked will be turned on.

The thing is, after I click on the one not initially checked, they both turn off "forever".

I have debugged by code, and up to the call to `setState` everything works. The state is set as I want it to be set, but the buttons are not updating.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = this.createInitialState({celsiusChecked: true})
    this.handleRadioTicked = this.handleRadioTicked.bind(this)
  }

  createInitialState(additionalState={}){
    let state = {
      fahrenheitChecked: false,
      celsiusChecked: false
    }

    state = Object.assign(state, additionalState)

    return state
  }

  handleRadioTicked(event){
    event.preventDefault()

    let radioName = event.target.name
    let stateProperty

    if (radioName === 'c'){
      stateProperty = 'celsiusChecked'
    } else if (radioName === 'f'){
      stateProperty = 'fahrenheitChecked'
    } else {
      throw Exception("something bad happened...probably the input field names have changed")
    }

    let newState = this.createInitialState()
    newState[stateProperty]= true;

    // the newState is calculated OK. Checked for both buttons.
    // Also, initially, the buttons render properly
    this.setState(newState) 
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
          <form>
            <fieldset>
              <input type="radio" name="f" value="fahrenheit" checked={this.state.fahrenheitChecked} onChange={this.handleRadioTicked}/>
              <label htmlFor="f">Fahrenheit</label>
              <input type="radio" name="c" value="celsius" checked={this.state.celsiusChecked} onChange={this.handleRadioTicked}/>
              <label htmlFor="c">Celsius</label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am running this example with this codepen setup, which is what facebook provided: http://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ZpvBNJ?editors=0010

Am I missing anything?

*[EDIT]* i updated the name of the inputs, and corrected the code. A different issue: Now the inputs NEVER change state. I debugged and the `setState` method is called with the proper state, however the buttons don't switch state. I put a breakpoint before the `this.setState` call, and the buttons looked ok then. They are being switched back to the initial state however after that point somewhere. I should probably try to put a DOM breakpoint of some kind....

The new code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = this.createInitialState({celsiusChecked: true})
    this.handleRadioTicked = this.handleRadioTicked.bind(this)

    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this)
  }

  createInitialState(additionalState={}){
    let state = {
      fahrenheitChecked: false,
      celsiusChecked: false
    }

    state = Object.assign(state, additionalState)

    return state
  }

  handleRadioTicked(event){
    event.preventDefault()

    let radioValue = event.target.value
    let stateProperty

    if (radioValue === 'celsius'){
      stateProperty = 'celsiusChecked'
    } else if (radioValue === 'fahrenheit'){
      stateProperty = 'fahrenheitChecked'
    } else {
      throw Exception("something bad happened...probably the input field names have changedx")
    }

    let newState = this.createInitialState()
    newState[stateProperty]= true;

    // Here the newState is succesfully created each time
    // ...still, the radio buttons don't "react" appropriately - pardon the pun
    this.setState(newState) 
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
          <form>
            <fieldset>
              <input type="radio" name="scale" value="fahrenheit" checked={this.state.fahrenheitChecked} onChange={this.handleRadioTicked}/>
              <label htmlFor="f">Fahrenheit</label>
              <input type="radio" name="scale" value="celsius" checked={this.state.celsiusChecked} onChange={this.handleRadioTicked}/>
              <label htmlFor="c">Celsius</label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Radio inputs should have the same `name` attribute.

Comment: @idbehold thanks, but that didn't do it. I updated my question. SOmething doesn't let the buttons change state at all now.

Answer (score 3):

for the radio button the name attribute of the two input must match

```
<input type="radio" name="f"
```

change both names to "f" or some other string and try again.

See example below

```
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
```

Comment: thanks, but that didn't work. I updated the answer with some code.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is too old, but it can help someone.

Try to remove the `event.preventDefault()` when you use this you prevent the main functionality of the radio button the toggle.

Comment: OMG, is the second time I see this as a suggestion to my issues. And it is the only that has helped me in both cases and solved my issue immediately. I should probably use it way more often if something comes up. Literally, it helped me solve a problem I had for 3 - 4 days!

Answer (score 1):

My problem, with ReactJS, was that I was defining the `checked` attribute of my radio buttons instead of the `defaultChecked` one !